# Javascript Append function won't duplicate img src on each card

Tags: javascript, php, append

I have the following code that is suppose to loop through the arrays and print a card out for each one.  It works when I hardcode my img src to a path on my computer.  When I try and use my image array, my cards stop duplicating.  I know my array is populated because I pull from it in another place in my code.  I am evidently not putting the right quotes around stuff.  Can someone see anything wrong?

```
    var names= <?php echo json_encode($Names); ?>;
    var colors= <?php echo json_encode($Color); ?>;
    var Images= <?php echo base64_encode($Image); ?>;

    //Can use variable as selector, not that I'm using a specific selector
    //Try using array of arrays and pick one to each loop over
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {

            $.each(colors, 
                function(i, value) {
                    $('.main_card_shell').append(
                    "<div class='card_content card_style' id='card0'>" +

                           "<div class='subcard_style box_title'>" + 
                           "<img class='card_image' src='data:image/png;base64, " + Images[i] + "' alt='Item #1' />" +      


                               '<div class="profile">' +
                                   '<div class="card_number">' + value + '</div>' +
                                   '<div class="card_name">' + names[i] + '</div>' +
                                   '<div class="tag_row">' +
                                       '<div class="sample_item sample_item4"></div>' +
                                       '<div class="sample_item sample_item3"></div>' +
                                   '</div>' +
                               '</div>' +
                           '</div>   ' +
                           "<div class='subcard_style box_status'>" +
```

Comment: Please, any ideas would be helpful.  I am trying everything and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes look fine in my eyes. But because Images is not an array

```
var Images= <?php echo base64_encode($Image); ?>;
```

this can't work

```
"<img class='card_image' src='data:image/png;base64, " + Images[i] + "' alt='Item #1' />"
```

[update]

In your php code you are using base64_encode($image[$i]). But with

```
var Images= <?php echo base64_encode($Image); ?>;
```

you are encoding the array, not the images in the array. Try this instead:

```
var Images = []; 
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($image); $i += 1) {
  echo 'Images['.$i.'] = "'.base64_encode($image[$i]).'";';
}
?>
```

That way the value of each item in your javascript array Images is the base64_encoded 
representation of the value in your php array $image.

Make sure, the spelling of $image is right. In your comment you are using $image[0] but in your code snippet it's $Image.

Comment: But names[I] is working and I am setting it just like Images.  At the very top of my file, I am setting $Image as an array by $Image[] = $row['image'];  It is getting pulled from my database.                In another part of my code, I am using the image array and it is working.                              <?php
                                echo '<img class="card_image" src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( image[0] ).'" alt="Item #1" />';
                            ?>.     Something about the function and append is not liking me using a variable for img src

Comment: So it seems, your php array $image is working. But your javascript array Images 
is not. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Roger that.  One thing that is making me scratch my head is that even if I don't use any array.  I set a var = "C://path on computer" and use that instead of my array, it still quits working.  So that makes me think it is a syntax error as opposed to my array.  If I take this same C:// path and just hard code it in (i.e. without using a variable) it makes my function work.  It is something about me setting img src to a variable that is breaking my code.  Does that make any sense to you.  I feel like I am missing something simple.

Comment: @BEP I can't really tell without seeing the code that you tried. My guess is, there 
are two different problems. One might be a quotes-problem when you use an array of paths to your images. The other is base64 encoding something else than the image data. Using the path might be a better solution, because the base64 strings can make your js-array really big. But that would be another question. ;)